# how to save numbers only from an array into a new array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I currently have var: `$_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid']` which gives me the following output:

```
Array{"returned_val":["47483647","47483647","47483647","665414807","263901486","665414807","665414807","665414807"]}
```

Im looking to save the data here into a new array, containing only the numbers in a format of; `47483647, 47483647, etc`

The objective is to use it in a sql query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM vote WHERE
vote_fb_uid IN ($myNumbers)
```

Saving it into a new array I figured could be done like so:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid'] as $uid) {
    $uids[] = $uid['id'];
}

$ids = join(',', $uids);
```

However my issue remains, how to "clean" the first var to contain numbers only.
Suggestions?

Comment: Try `foreach ($REQUEST['fb_friend_uid']->returned_val as $uid)....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you an *exact* solution, because I'm not sure if the value returned by `$_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid']` is a PHP array printed using `json_encode()`, or the value is actually a json string.

In either case, where is an example which makes use of both circumstances, so use whichever one makes sense in your scenario:

**If PHP Array:**

Assumes PHP Array has a format similar to:

array('returned_val' => array('47483647', '47483647', '47483647', '665414807', '263901486', '665414807', '665414807', '665414807'));

```
<?php
$original_arr = $_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid']['returned_val'];
```

**If JSON String:**

Assumes the JSON String has a format similar to:

{"returned_val":["47483647","47483647","47483647","665414807","263901486","665414807","665414807","665414807"]}

```
<?php
$json_arr = json_decode($_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid'], True);
$original_arr = $json_arr['returned_val'];
```

**Then, use this code:**

```
<?php
// Extract only whole number values, omit anything which is not a 0-9 character.
$filtered_arr = array_filter($original_arr, 'ctype_digit');

// Escape values to remove possibility of SQL injection.
$filtered_arr = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $filtered_arr);

// Convert the array to a string
$string_arr = "'" . implode("','", $filtered_arr) . "'";

// Perform SQL Query
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote WHERE vote_fb_uid IN ($string_arr)");
```

Comment: Hi Joshua,

Your sugeestions would actually solve my above described issue - so accepting your answer- I found out that the description I made here was based on totally wrong data, so tried something else. Thanks again for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the array using [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
$uids =  array_filter($_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid'], 'is_numeric');
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter for numbers you can use [is_numeric( mixed $var )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

But if you need more control (only integers of certain type, length) you can either use REGEX or is_numeric and some ifs.

Comment: rather than using REGEX, i'd recommend PHP's built-in method for determining whether a given value is a whole number or not: `ctype_digit()`

Answer (score -3):

This looks like a json string, so use http://php.net/json_decode

Maybe you need to remove `Array` at the beginning (but I don't know if Array is actual in the variable), use http://php.net/substr

```
$jsonString = substr($_REQUEST['fb_friend_uid'], 5);
$fb_friend_uid = json_decode($jsonString);
$ids = join(',', $fb_friend_uid['returned_val']);
```